# Model loyality effect of returning customers

Tags: time-series, modeling, churn

I have customers which book an offer about once a year. I'd like to determine if there is a "loyality effect" - i.e. a customer from this year is more likely to book next year again.

I can see that after booking this year, a customer will most likely book either about one year later, or next January. Moreover, just by chance an arbitrary customer will book with me (with a general demand peak in January or Midyear).

Can you suggest an approach to split and quantify these effects from booking dates I know for my customers? (therefore I know: customer1:[date1, date2, ...], customer2:[date3, ...], ...)

I'd like to separate the general random demand from the loyality bonus. Any ideas?

Comment: There is too little information here to say much, and thats why you get no responses so far. Tell us more!   Maybe a logistic regression with a dummy for repeat customer?

Comment: I think with the given data structure there isn't much more to describe. I have customer IDs and booking dates per customer only. I assume some customers return by chance and some become loyal. Using years of booking for non-loyal customers: `P(2014)=P(2014|2013)=P(2014|2013,2012)=...`. For loyal: `P_l(2014|2013)>P(2014|2013)`.

Comment: So you dont have non-arrival data? then logistic regression is a poor fit ... Maybe start with making tables (per, per week, per weekday --- depends on amouit of data, among others) of percent of arrivals that are repeat arrivals ...  at least a start.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I have about one booking per year. So I consider years (even though continuous would be better). For each customer I know in which year he has booked. For example I know that `P(2014|2013)=10%`, `P(2014|2013,2012)=20%`, `P(2014|2013,2012,2011)=35%` (e.g. the latter meaning that of all customers who booked [at least once] in 2011,2012,2013 35% have also booked in 2014. Does the mean I have some loyal customers since the base rate is 10%? How many?